# is there code to automatically resize an image based on predetermined pixel width?

Tags: html, image

I have been working on my site for my store and have multiple pages with products arranged in a table. First column is a photo of the item followed by columns with item #, description, price, etc.. Currently I am writing code for each image resize "img height:, img width:" Is there code that would automatically do this for each image? I am trying to keep the width the same on all photos to keep the column the same but the height is usually different for each photo. I am just trying to keep them proportional. Just trying to figure out a way of doing this easier. I've tried many design-your-site websites but none offer subpages of subpages. Wesbite is www.fredstrainshop.com. "lionel.html" link gives a good example of what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't this style work? `img{ width: 100%; height: auto;}` work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class for each image and specify the width and height. In case you want to change height of some specific elements use id.

HTML-

```
 <body>
        <img class="train" src="http://www.fredstrainshop.com/6-39534.jpg">
        <img class="train" src="http://www.fredstrainshop.com/6-39563.jpg">
    </body>
```

CSS-

```
 .train
   {
      border: 1px solid black;
      width: 100px;
   }
```

See this for inspiration - https://jsfiddle.net/0w0vkzst/

On another note, I just visited your website, please consider using classes and ids for arriving at a more modular design. You might want to brush your html skills, for that [codecademy](https://codecademy.com) and [w3school](https://w3schools.com)s are great sites.

Answer (score 0):

I used this html line

```
style="width:100%;height:100%;"
```

The line won't work in my case because the scrollpane works a little bit differently.
But if I add this line:

```
<img src="images/album/thumbs/1.jpg" alt="images/album/1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:100%;"/>
```

it works